# Display A Message If Filesize Is Smaller Than 30 KBytes

Tags: linux, bash, fedora

I have a Zenity message box in a script

`zenity --info --text='done' > /dev/null 2>&1`

I need to pop up a message, e.g.: "file is smaller then 30 KBytes!" when a file is smaller then 30 KBytes.

How could I write an "if then else" script to pop up a zenity message, when e.g.: "FILE" is smaller then 30 KByte?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $(stat --printf="%s" FILENAME) -lt 30720 ]; then
    zenity --info --text='file is smaller then 30 KBytes!' > /dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

These examples use syntax that is specific to more modern shells such as Bash, ksh and zsh.

Some systems don't have `stat` and you [shouldn't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

```
result=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "$file" -size -30k)
if [[ ${result##*/} = $file ]]
then
    zenity --info --text='The file is smaller then 30 KBytes!' > /dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

Where "30k" equals 30720. If you'd prefer, you can use `-size -30000c`.

If you do have `stat`:

```
size=$(stat -c '%s' "$file")
if (( size < 30720 ))    # or you could use 30000
then
    zenity --info --text='The file is smaller then 30 KBytes!' > /dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SIZE=`ls -l $1 | awk '{print $5}'`

if [ $SIZE -lt 30720 ]
then
        zenity --info --text='File is smaller than 30KB' > /dev/null 2>&1
fi
```